# При откате windows программы удаляются не полностью

Tags: windows-10

Тестирую использование точек восстановления в windows.

Windows 10. Создал точку восстановления (пусть будет v1). После скачал и установил программу. Затем откатил систему до момента, когда программа еще не была установлена (v1). Да, ярлык проги удалился. Но в папке program files (x86) - именно в эту папку устанавливалась прога - осталась папка программы с файлами; также в папке users - myname - appdata - roaming осталась папка программы с файлами. Почему так?

P.S. программа для теста была notepad++, все тестировалось за один день: создавалась точка, устанавливалась прога, делался откат, но не думаю, что это как-то может повлиять.

Comment: Потому что точка отката ни разу не снапшот. Вот откат в теневую копию прибил бы всё лишнее.

Comment: Почитал про теневые копии, буду тестить, спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 0):

Откат системы работает с конкретными типами файлов - преимущественно, исполняемыми. Файлы, которые потенциально похожи на пользовательские файлы, он не затрагивает.

PS: А к удалению программ вопрос вообще не имеет никакого отношения: оно делается деинсталлятором самой программы, соответственно удаляется всё, что посчитает нужным её разработчик. Ну или удалит случайно, вплоть до всего содержимого системного диска.

Comment: Ух ты, не знал. Понял, принял. Спасибо за ваш ответ.